# Sum Left using array formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of mixed text and numbers I can't change (or add helper columns). E.g:

```
1 hour
3 hours
2 hours
```

I need to add the numeric parts only (so the total would be 6 in this example). I'd have thought an array formula along the lines of this would work:

```
={SUM(LEFT(F16:F23),1)}
```

but it returns an incorrect value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the array formula:

```
=SUM(--LEFT(F16:F23,1))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To handle blanks, use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(F16:F23<>"",(--LEFT(F16:F23,1))))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

**How it Works:**

1. the `LEFT()` function creates an array of first characters
2. the `IF()` makes sure there is a first character
3. the double negative converts the characters into numbers
4. the `SUM()` functions adds them up.

Comment: Works great, thanks. However, unless all cells in the range are populated it returns a value error, any idea how to handle blanks?

Comment: @Absinthe  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: @Absinthe  By the way, there is a far better way to do this *(if you can control the data)*

Comment: Always the best approach I know, but not possible in this situation unfortunately, my client wants to keep the spredsheet exactly as is.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if this answer included an explanation of "how it works"(tm)

Comment: @Hannu  see my **update**

Comment: ... so `--string_expression` <=> `VALUE(string_expression)`